# Is there any work around for indexing list in Apche ignite and use in where clause?

Tags: ignite

I am not sure how to index List/array in apache ignite. I want to use my list/array in where clause, I can write custom function but it will search all the data set, But I am looking for indexing of list/array.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

A common way to store lists in SQL database is to create a table of pairs, representing one-to-many relation.

Columns of this table of pairs can be indexed and used in `where` clauses after joining with the initial table.

To make joins work fast, you will probably need to make records of these two tables [collocated by affinity](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/affinity-collocation).